# Procedure or function 'employee_pro' expects parameter '@empid', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have  been trying to execute a GridView. Here, my database name is test and stored procedure name is employee_pro. But, it continuously showing the same error. What would be the necessary solution?

```
namespace Insert_update_delete_Stored_Pro
{

public partial class StoredProcedure : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString;

    SqlCommand com;
    SqlDataAdapter sqlda;
    DataSet ds;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();
        }
    }

    protected void BindGrid()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

        com = new SqlCommand();
        con.Open();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.CommandText = "employee_pro";
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));                           
        com.Parameters["@status"].Value = "Display";
        sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        ds = new DataSet();
        sqlda.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }



    protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {

        GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

        BindGrid();

    }



    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

        BindGrid();

    }



    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName.Equals("Add"))
        {

            TextBox txtname = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddname");

            TextBox txtaddress = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddaddress");

            TextBox txtdesignation = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAdddesignation");

            string name, address, designation;

            name = txtname.Text;

            address = txtaddress.Text;

            designation = txtdesignation.Text;

            Addemployee(name, address, designation);

            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

            BindGrid();

        }

    }

    protected void Addemployee(string name, string address, string designation)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        con.Open();
        com = new SqlCommand();
        com.CommandText = "employee_pro"; 
        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
        com.Connection = con; 
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empid", SqlDbType.Int)); 
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)); 
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)); 
        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@designation", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)); 
        com.Parameters["@status"].Value = "Add"; 
        com.Parameters["@name"].Value = name; 
        com.Parameters["@address"].Value = address; 
        com.Parameters["@designation"].Value = designation; 
        sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(com); 
        ds = new DataSet(); 
        sqlda.Fill(ds); 
        con.Close(); 
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

        Label empid = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblempid");

        string eid = empid.Text;

        Deleteemployee(eid);

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

        BindGrid();

    }

    protected void Deleteemployee(string empid)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

        com = new SqlCommand();

        com.CommandText = "employee_pro";

        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        com.Connection = con;

        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));

        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empid", SqlDbType.Int));

        com.Parameters["@status"].Value = "Delete";

        com.Parameters["@empid"].Value = empid;

        sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

        ds = new DataSet();

        sqlda.Fill(ds);

        con.Close();

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {

        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

        BindGrid();

    }



    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {

        Label empid = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblempid");

        TextBox name = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtname");

        TextBox address = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtaddress");

        TextBox designation = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtdesignation");

        string eid = empid.Text;

        string ename = name.Text;

        string eaddress = address.Text;

        string edesignation = designation.Text;

        Updateemployee(eid, ename, eaddress, edesignation);

        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

        BindGrid();

    }



    protected void Updateemployee(string empid, string name, string address, string designation)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

        com = new SqlCommand();

        con.Open();

        com.Connection = con;

        com.CommandText = "employee_pro";

        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empid", SqlDbType.Int));

        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));

        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));

        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));

        com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@designation", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50));

        com.Parameters["@empid"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(empid.ToString());

        com.Parameters["@status"].Value = "Update";

        com.Parameters["@name"].Value = name;

        com.Parameters["@address"].Value = address;

        com.Parameters["@designation"].Value = designation;

        sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);

        ds = new DataSet();

        sqlda.Fill(ds);

        con.Close();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: What is the definition of `employee_pro` sp? In your `BindGrid` method, you didn't add `@empid` as a parameter.

Comment: You don't seem to be supplying a value for `@empid`.

Comment: Error message is self explanatory!

Comment: @Sumi, could you please supply a stack trace with the error? Which method fails?

Comment: Not supplying  @empid  input parameter for employee_pro procedure in BindGrid method. Please check.

Comment: can you please specify the relevent code for supplying value for empid in BindGrid method?

Comment: actually i tried to add the empid parameter once but it again shows the same error. I might have done syntax error previously, so i would like to request for a specific additional code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `Addemployee()`, you have added a parameter as follows:

```
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empid", SqlDbType.Int));
```

But you have not specified the value of the parameter. Hence, add the following line

```
com.Parameters["@empid"].Value = <Generate Your Employee Id Here>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add another parameter in BingGrid function that is @empid . Provide an empid to display the results related to that empid

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that you are missing a parameter.

You are supposed to add `@empid` to your `BindGrid()` method:

```
//assuming your empid parameter is of type int
com.Parameters.Add("@empid", SqlDbType.Int);
com.Parameters["@empid"].Value = valueforEmpId;
```

Or:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@empid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = valueforEmpId;
```

If Empid is supposed to be null or empty use

```
 com.Parameters["@empid"].Value = DBNull.Value
```

Comment: Please read - Can we stop using `AddWithValue` - http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: There's always room for improvement. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As stated already by lots of people, you need to supply the employee ID to the BindGrid() function. You have an example of how to obtain it in your RowUpdating method.

However, you should probably consider making it an optional parameter in your stored procedure. I can't imagine how you would need to supply an emp ID parameter to the stored procedure when deleting an employee, for example. You probably need to do some redesign around your stored procedure usage.